# How to disable button when checkbox is checked.vbscript

Tags: vbscript

How to disable button when checkbox is checked and enable it when a condition is met using vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub disableButton()  
  If checkMultiple.value = 1 Then  
    document.form1.cmdButton7.enabled = False 
  End If  
End Sub


Sub enableButton()  
    document.form1.cmdButton7.enabled = False 
End Sub  


<input type="checkbox" name="checkMultiple" id="Multiple" onclick="disableButton()">Multiple
```

Comment: i tried the method but i got the object required "checkMultiple" error. 

Sub disableButton()
 If checkMultiple.value = 1 Then 
 document.form1.cmdButton7.enabled = False 
 ElseIf sum = 100 Then 
 document.form1.cmdButton7.enabled = true
 End If 
End Sub 



<input type="checkbox" name="checkMultiple" id="Multiple" onclick="disableButton">Multiple

Answer (score 0):

i tried the method but i got the object required "checkMultiple" error. 
Sub disableButton() 
If checkMultiple.value = 1 Then 
document.form1.cmdButton7.enabled = False
ElseIf sum = 100 Then 
document.form1.cmdButton7.enabled = true 
End If 
End Sub

Multiple